# Lion not responding to mouse clicks over VNC

Tags: macos, mouse, remote-desktop

Under Snow Leopard, I had no problems with VNC connections from my Windows 7 64-bit PC to my Mac mini. However, after upgrading to Lion, my Mac mini no longer responds to mouse clicks when using any VNC client on my PC. Oddly, the local cursor is moving and the Mac also responds to keyboard events - I just can't click anything.

I have enabled Screen Sharing/Remote Management and enabled VNC in System Preferences (obviously) and have checked Observe -> Control in the settings.

Has anyone experienced this or have a possible fix/suggestion? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very popular issue. VNC server is not the only thing that has problem working with Lion.

I think the problem stems from the fact that; Lion can handle multiple user connections. So to make it work, you need to logout of your Mac first then try connecting remotely. More information in this forum..

http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-1193137.html